# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required Rails Mailer using environmental variable on config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I'm using Rails Mailer to send confirmation mails on my app, and I've set up my `config>environment>development.rb` like below:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    # user_name: ENV["MAIL_USERNAME"],
    # password: ENV["MAIL_PASSWORD"],
    user_name: "myemail@mydomain.com",
    password: "myCorrectPassword",
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

**Problem**

When I hardcode the `user_name` and the `password` for `"myemail@mydomain.com"` and `"myCorrectPassword"`, the mailer sends an email and it works fine. But when I use the ENV to make sure that my credentials are safe, I get the `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required` error.

On Terminal, I checked my ENV to make sure that I've entered correct values for each variable, and they were right.

What else can I try?

Comment: maybe the credentials wasn't configured for development environment in config/application.yml

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you run this in rails console ENV["MAIL_USERNAME"] ??
Does your ~/.bash_profile has this

```
  export MAIL_USERNAME="myemail@mydomain.com"
```

Try to source ~/.bash_profile once

Comment: I get the correct values when I check in bash. I’m not sure what the problem was but I solved it using figaro gem.